# Does the equation $x^2 = 733$ have a solution in $\Bbb Z_{1001}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does the equation $x^2 = 733$ have a solution in $\Bbb Z_{1001}$?Is Quadratic Residues to solve the problem?

Comment: $1001=7\cdot 11\cdot 13$. First ask yourself whether it has a solution modulo $7,11,13$ and see if you can get to any conclusions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: The question is in large part whether $733$ is a *quadratic residue* mod $7$ etc.  The key idea, at least for big numbers, is *quadratic recprocity*.

Answer (score 6):

$$x^2\equiv 733\ (\bmod\ 1001)$$

implies $$x^2\equiv 5\ (\bmod\ 7)$$

This equivalence has no solution.

Comment: If $1001$ divides $x^2-733$, then $7$ does also divide $x^2-733$ and therefore $x^2-5$.